# Read in special characters in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am reading in values in from a .txt file. One of these values is written like this: één (its an utf-8 file). However when I read it in python its written like this: '\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa9n'

Any thoughts on how I can write it in like: één?

Im using python 2.7 (so decode() does not work

Comment: Please provide your python version and your code that reads this in, we cannot reverse engineer your code from the result

Comment: "when I read it in Python it's written like this:" "written" where and how ???

Comment: "Im using python 2.7 (so decode() does not work" => `str.decode(encoding)` DOES work in Python 2.7 if you provide the correct encoding - but it's only useful if your point is to get a `unicode` string.

Comment: python 2.7 'str' doesn't store Unicode. When you load Unicode data into the `str` , you must specify correct encoding when reading from a file. Afterwards,  python2 `print` will display the binary encoded data in whatever default codepage font. Here is the TL;DR; documentation of python 2.7 unicode https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: @mootmoot this is technically correct but still irrelevant wrt/ the OP's question - his content is obviously correctly encoded, and what he complains about is seeing the internal representation of the string (as given by `repr()`) instead of the rendering.

Answer (score 3):

If you just display the `str` object in your python shell what you see is the internal representation of the string. If you print the string to something (which supports your string's encoding) then you'll see the expected result (NB : here 'toto.txt' is an utf8-encoded file with 'één' inside, and - obviously - my terminal is configured to use utf-8).

```
bruno@bigb:~/Work$ cat toto.txt 
één

bruno@bigb:~/Work$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open("toto.txt") as f:
...     stuff = f.read().strip()
... 
>>> stuff
'\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa9n'
>>> print stuff
één
>>> print repr(stuff)
'\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa9n'
>>>
```

Comment: You're assuming the console/terminal is UTF-8. In general it needs to be decoded to Unicode before printing, so Python can encode it to `sys.stdout.encoding`. If that fails it will need to be encoded manually using a `'replace'`, `'backslashreplace'`, or `'ignore'` handler.

Comment: @eryksun I indeed use utf as system encoding (why use anythin else) but this is totally unrelated.  If the OP sees '\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa9n' when he "writes" his string then what he sees is the internal representation. If I reencode the same string to say latin1 and do a mere `>>> stuff` in my python shell what I get is `'\xe9\xe9n'`, which is the internal representation of the same string in latin1 endcoding. If I `print` it instead, i get "��n" instead, not '\xe9\xe9n' (of course...)

Comment: Yes, but that's nonsense mojibake and couldn't be more wrong. We don't want that. We want to print the best approximation to the original string that the current console/terminal supports. That means we have to decode the UTF-8 string first, preferably by reading it as Unicode from the start via `io.open`.

Comment: I do agree that using a Unicode terminal/console is best, e.g. for Windows support I recommend depending on `win_unicode_console` for text-mode scripts, which allows printing UTF-8 and internally converts to the Windows native UTF-16 encoding -- since the console's support for UTF-8 has too many bugs to be useful. But even if we want Unicode, we should still fall back to the best we can do for the current terminal rather than spewing random mojibake at the user.

Comment: @eryksun "I do agree that using a Unicode terminal/console is best" : actually neither utf-8 nor utf-16 are unicode. But anyway:  __none__ of this has anything to do with the OP problem, which is confusing the internal representation of a string with the rendering of the same string.

Comment: You said "If you print the string to something (which supports your string's encoding) then you'll see the expected result". Not necessarily. Depending on the terminal if you just print UTF-8 bytes to it you may actually see mojibake nonsense (guaranteed to be nonsense in stock Python 2 on Windows), which is no better than seeing the representation itself.

Comment: As to my statement about a Unicode terminal, it's implied that arbitrary Unicode data sent to a terminal has to be encoded in a format that supports all of Unicode, which for most of us means a UTF encoding. What I didn't say is that unfortunately the Windows console doesn't support all of Unicode, only the BMP. So even the best we can do in a script running on the Windows console will be lacking (e.g. emoji characters).

Comment: @eryksun I already answered on this : "I indeed use utf8 as system encoding". And this is STILL irrelevant - the OP does not complain about mojibake or encoding/decoding error or whatever but about seeing the internal representation of the string.

Comment: The OP explicitly asked "Any thoughts on how I can write it in like: één?".

Comment: Yes, but without specifying what he meant by "write". And I already gave the only sensible answer so far (until the OP cares to explain what he means by "writing" that is). If he then complains about mojibake or encoding errors the it will be time to talk about unicode etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python3:

```
>> data = b'\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa9n'
>> data.decode()
'één'
```

Comment: I am using 2.7.

Comment: What happens when you do: `print data`